# how to containerize a Django project with Oracle Database

Tags: django, oracle, docker

I am trying to containerize my Django project and set up a docker image for the Oracle Database. I am getting an error while I run **docker-compose build**:

> service "oracle-db" refers to undefined volume oracle: invalid compose
> project

My docker-compose file is:

```
 version: "3"

 services:
     django:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: django.Dockerfile
image: kanbanboard_django
restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  - "django-static:/app/django-static"
  - "media:/app/media"
  - "./backend/settings:/app/settings"
env_file:
  - .env
depends_on:
  - oracle-db

certbot:
  image: certbot/certbot
  entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
volumes:
  - "./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt"
  - "./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot"

 oracle-db:
  image: sath89/oracle-19c
  volumes:
    - oracle:/u01/app/oracle/
  env_file:
    - .env

 volumes:
  media:
  django-static:
```

Comment: Review all the docker resources in the Oracle containers repo: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase.  Also see https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe maintained by one of Oracle's product managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your volume at the end of your docker-compose in order to use it in your container.

You should replace:

```
volumes:
  media:
  django-static:
```

by:

```
volumes:
  media:
  django-static:
  oracle:
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error when I do docker-compose up -d: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for sath89/oracle-19c, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: I managed to run docker compose up. The mistake was that it was a mismatched of the docker image name in the docker-compose file and the services file